# upload image to database (php)

Tags: php, mysql

I create simple html and php to upload image (long blob type) to database and show it. I tried different codes to implement that but didn't result.
This code have the same  idea but the image not upload in database but when I used "echo" to print name and content, it printed. Also, the result from code broken image.
I really don't know where it is problem !!!

**upload.php**

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"   >
  <label  for="file">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="image" id="image"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","")or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("databaseimage") or die(mysql_error());
  $image= mysql_real_escape_string( file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
  $image_name= mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);

  $image_type= mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["type"]);
  $image_size= $_FILES["image"]["size"];

  if(substr($image_type,0,5)=="image")
  {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'store' VALUSE ('','$image_name','$image')");
    echo "Image Uploaded";
    $lastid= mysql_insert_id();
    echo "Image Uploaded. </p> Your Image: </p> <img src=\"get.php?id=$lastid\"/>";
  }
}
?>
```

**get.php**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","")or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("databaseimage") or die(mysql_error());
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
  $id= mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['id']);
  $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'store' WHERE 'id'='$id'");
  while( $raw=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
  {
    $imageData=$raw["image"];
  }
  header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
  echo $imageData;
}
else
{
  echo "Error!...";
}
?>
```

Comment: Should try to isolate your problem more with some debugging. One problem, in your sql statement: "VALUSE" should be "VALUES"

Comment: You might have an easier time getting this to work with PDO.  At a minimum, you won't be writing new code against a deprecated API.

Answer (score 0):

Change `'` to `:

upload.php

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `store` VALUES ('','$image_name','$image')");
```

get.php

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `store` WHERE `id`='$id'");
```

**mysql_*** functions is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: @Dalal Solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_real_escape_string` escapes a lot of characters that will most likely end up corrupting the data inside of your image.

You could try encoding it with something like b64 instead of trying to escape it if you're afraid of SQL injection (or better yet, combine the encoding with something like PDO).

**Storing** the image:

```
$image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
```

**Retrieving** the encoded image:

```
<?php
// decode the image
$imageData = base64_decode($raw["image"]);

// get the file extension
$filename = basename($raw["name"]);
$file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename,"."),1));

// set the appropriate content header
switch( $file_extension ) {
    case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
    case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
    case "jpeg":
    case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
    default:
}

header('Content-type: ' . $ctype);

echo $imageData;
?>
```